# Why can't we do multiple response.send in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

3 years ago I could do multiple `res.send` in express.js.
even write a `setTimeout` to show up a live output.

```
response.send('<script class="jsbin" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>');
response.send('<html><body><input id="text_box" /><button>submit</button></body></html>');
var initJs = function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $.post('/input', { input: $('#text_box').val() }, function() { alert('has send');});
  });
}
response.send('<script>' + initJs + '</script>');
```

Now it will throw:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent
```

I know nodejs and express have updated. Why can't do that now? Any other idea?

---

Found the solution but `res.write` is not in api reference http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html

Comment: There is a line on the API reference page says "The res object is an enhanced version of Node’s own response object and supports all built-in fields and methods", response.write is a built-in method.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Maybe you need: `response.write`

```
response.write("foo");
response.write("bar");
//...
response.end()
```

`res.send` implicitly calls `res.write` followed by `res.end`. If you call `res.send` multiple times, it will work the first time. However, since the first `res.send` call ends the response, you cannot add anything to the response.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like that's probably what he was thinking of. I completely forgot about Node's `response.write`; my brain was in Express land :/

Comment: Cool, this's I want. But, Why it's not in api reference http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send ???

Comment: Maybe because we should use `res.render` or `res.send`, I use `res.write` when I was a newbie. @emj365 why not try `res.render`?

Comment: `respone.write` and `response.writeHead` are from the `http.ServerResponse` api [node doc](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding)

Answer (score 21):

`response.send` sends an entire HTTP response to the client, including headers and content, which is why you are unable to call it multiple times. In fact, it even ends the response, so there is no need to call `response.end` explicitly when using `response.send`.

It appears to me that you are attempting to use `send` like a buffer: writing to it with the intention to flush later. This is not how the method works, however; you need to build up your response in code and then make a single `send` call.

Unfortunately, I cannot speak to why or when this change was made, but I know that it has been like this at least since Express 3.

Answer (score 1):

**`res.write` immediately sends bytes to the client**

I just wanted to make this point about `res.write` clearer.

It does not build up the reply and wait for `res.end()`. It just sends right away.

This means that the first time you call it, it will send the HTTP reply headers including the status in order to have a meaningful response. So if you want to set a status or custom header, you have to do it before that first call, much like with `send()`.

Note that `write()` is not what you usually want to do in a simple web application. The browser getting the reply little by little increases the complexity of things, so you will only want to do it it if it is really needed.

**Use `res.locals` to build the reply across middleware**

This was my original use case, and `res.locals` fits well. I can just store data in an Array there, and then on the very last middleware join them up and do a final `send` to send everything at once, something like:

```
  async (err, req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.msg = ['Custom handler']
    next(err)
  },
  async (err, req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.msg.push('Custom handler 2')
    res.status(500).send(res.locals.msg.join('\n'))
  }
```