# express.js, why res.write not in api reference

Tags: node.js, express

Form my another question [can't do multiple res.send in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542521/cant-do-multiple-res-send-in-express-js/25545247#25545247)

Can't find "res.write" in http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html

**here is code example:**

```
response.write("foo");
response.write("bar");
//...
response.end()
```

Comment: Something about inheriting from the NodeJS response from the http module if I had to guess. You can read about it in the NodeJS http module docs.

Comment: Here is the api reference http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `res.write` isn't part of express API. This is a server without express:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hi,');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.O.O.1');
```

So you see the `http` module already has already that req and res arguments, and express make do with adding properties to these objects.