# How to send response using twice or more callback in one request

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I'm using express and the request POST look like that

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
 var data = req.body;
 getRandom(data, function(value){
     res.json({value: value});
 });
});
```

POST is sent through ajax and then update textarea with new data.

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/",
           data: JSON.stringify(datareq),
           dataType: 'json',
           contentType: 'application/json',
           success: function(x){
               $.each(x, function(index, value) {
                  $('.textarea').append(value + '\n');
               });
           },
           error: function(x) {
                console.log(x + 'error');
          }
       });
```

How to send this using one POST and a few response. User received one data in textarea when cb finished and then another data and so one till  the end.

```
<textarea>
 data 1 - 1sec
 data 2 - 2sec leater
 data 3 - 3 second later
 ...
</textarea>
```

I add Time (1sec ...) only to show that callback has a lot to do to send another response.

Of course this not working because res.send() close connection and I received error

So how to achieve my idea, to sending simultaneously after post request. I want to give user data very fast, then another one when is ready not waiting for all and then send response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't**

---

**Reason:**

Http closes connection after sending response. You can not keep it open and sending multiple responses to the client. HTTP doesn't support it.

**Solution 1:**

Simply put a timer at client side and request periodically.

**Solution 2 (Recommended):**

Use socket, and pass data through it. [socket.io](https://socket.io/) is the socket library for `nodejs` applications. It is very easy to use. Set up a connection, keep sending data from server and receive it on client side.

---

Just to add on the answer. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25545247/9953550) explains why res.send closes the connection.