# Send a JSON array as response from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am fetching data from a MongoDB database then putting it in a cursor to send that as a Node.js response.

```
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB';
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //res.send('respond with a resource');
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var cursor = db.collection('Employee').find();
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {

      console.log(doc);
      arrayres = doc ;
     res.send(doc);

    });
    db.close();
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

It sends only the first record then I get this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.removeHeader (_http_outgoing.js:528:11)
    at ServerResponse.send
```

Notice: I get this error only when there are multiple records to send as response.

Comment: You can only send back one response to the browser (be it `res.send()`, `res.end()`, `res.sendFile()`, `res.json()` or any other). You can't have that inside a `.forEach()`.

Comment: how can i send an array at once then ?

Comment: Well, build an array, then send it once...

Comment: With Mongoose, you'd be like `Model.find().lean().exec( docs => res.json(docs))`

Comment: Posted a complete answer

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the response twice. Which is impossible ( look at [Why can't we do multiple response.send in Express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542521/why-cant-we-do-multiple-response-send-in-express-js) )

```
  res.send('respond with a resource');
```

Here and

```
res.send(arrayres);
```

Here.

Here is a working example based on jeremy's answer :

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        var cursor = db.collection('Employee').find();

        let employees = []
        const pushData = async () => {
            cursor.forEeach( function (doc) {
                employees.push(doc);
            });
        }
        const sendResponse = async () => {
            await pushData();
            res.json(employees);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: still having the same error even after sending a single response , please watch the post content update , thanks .

Comment: This is still the same issue, you are sending a response for each employee you have. You must send one and only one response.

Comment: Look at the edit i made. I hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can only send back one response to the browser (be it `res.send()`, `res.end()`, `res.sendFile()`, `res.json()` or any other). So, you can't have that inside a `.forEach()`.

First, build an array, then send your data back once.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        var cursor = db.collection('Employee').find();

        let employees = []

        cursor.forEeach( function (doc) {
            employees.push(doc);
        });

        res.json(employees);
    });
});
```

Or with Mongoose :

```
Employee.find().lean().exec( (err,docs) => res.json(docs))
```

Comment: thank you @jeremy Thille for your answer but i actually sending an empty array "[ ]" i think there is  a problem with push into the array

Comment: Yes, it should be `cursor.forEeach( function (doc)`. Fixed

Comment: still having the same issue  ! empty array sent to the browser .

Comment: Well that's a different problem. How to build the data you send back is something else. I don't use Mongo's native driver, so I don't know how to use `cursor`. Mongoose makes your life so much easier :) Anyway you get the idea, you can't use `res.end()` more than once.